# How send notification to Team user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have tried to send notifications to Microsoft teams. We have created a bot using this we can send but users want to initiate the conversation.

Also tried graph API shows 401 error.

We want to send notifications to Bot or API without the user initiating the conversation. i.e. sending notification direct to user chat.

Please help?

Comment: You can send message to user when he install the app using proactive messaging. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet)?

Comment: In this case, we want to create a conversation. User wants to send a message first.
We want to send a notification to Bot without the user initiating the conversation. i.e. sending notification direct to user chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can send message to user with out user interaction using graph API. Proactive messages are initiated by bots to start conversations with a user. They serve many purposes including sending welcome messages, conducting surveys or polls, and broadcasting organization-wide notifications. Proactive messages in Teams can be delivered as either ad-hoc or dialog-based conversations. Please check [Proactive installation of apps using Graph API and send messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages)

Comment: I have used graph api for sending message using the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. But it shows error like this.

<Response [401]>
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-04-04T18:42:24",
      "request-id": "05c567ee-9824-40d3-be10-6f90757edf19",
      "client-request-id": "05c567ee-9824-40d3-be10-6f90757edf19"
    }
  }
}

Comment: are you trying from graph explorer/postman?

Comment: I have used graph explorer.Also try in my python program

Comment: Could you please check the require permissions?